# Truffle compile --list not showing latest versions of compiler

Tags: truffle, blockchain, ethereumjs

truffle compile --list not showing version "0.8.0" and above.
truffle compile --list returns :

✖ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1

✖ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #2

✓ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #3

[ "0.7.1",
"0.7.0",
"0.6.12",
"0.6.11",
"0.6.10",
"0.6.9",
"0.6.8",
"0.6.7",
"0.6.5"
]

My versions are :

Truffle v5.5.7 (core: 5.5.7)

Ganache v^7.0.3

Solidity - 0.8.4 (solc-js)

Node v16.13.0

Web3.js v1.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how Truffle scans for Solidity Compilers version list.

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/473f8d4fc00f42026fcdf1b67f36ef045f054f91/packages/compile-solidity/src/compilerSupplier/loadingStrategies/VersionRange.ts#L23), Truffle currently uses three repositories to check compiler releases:

- #1 https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/bin/list.json
- #2 https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/list.json
- #3 https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/list.json

The first one is the only one containing updated releases; the others are deprecated.

For some reason (it happens more often than it should), the first repo was not reachable, so Truffle tried the second one (again, not reachable) and then the third one. The third one worked, but both the fallbacks repo are deprecated (see [here](https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin)), so only the first attempt can return updated values.

To fix this better, I [just proposed a PR](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/pull/5008) to use the latest suggested solc-bin repo, which is https://binaries.soliditylang.org/bin/list.json.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is working fine for me now. Able to fetch all latest versions.

Comment: Do we have a discord channel or community discussion platform ? @Giuseppe Bertone

Comment: You can use the channels dedicated to Truffle in the ConsenSys Discord (https://discord.gg/hYpHRjK) or the dedicated Gitter (https://gitter.im/ConsenSys/truffle)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated our relayer to point to the latest canonical URL (https://binaries.soliditylang.org/), so this should be fixed for everyone today.

Comment: Thanks a lot , it is working fine for me now. Able to fetch all latest versions.